# Qt 4 for symbian - If the project build by Qt4 Creator in mac, can it deploy to symbian by Window?

Tags: c++, qt, symbian, qt-creator, nokia

I cannot include the QCA in my project. And people says "Build Plugin / lib on mac" in easy.

So that i'm planning to build in on Mac (Qt4 Creator) and copy back to window for final deployment.

Is it ok? Any suggestion?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not also deply from Mac?
And if you plan to only create SIS package and sign it then you can do it everywhere - providing that you have all the needed files.

Comment: Because the simulator in Mac always crash. I need to reboot whenever it crashed.

Comment: OK, then develop in Windows :). Doesn't crash and is easier in the end

Comment: But it's super difficult to make use of library in window platform. I have no idea why it can't simply click "add button" and then done. It require i build the project of that library. But failed in Qt Creator and difficult to do in console (dos).......Is it possible to build it in other computer ?

Comment: Well, then build the library in Mac (I wonder if it supports also the Windows emulator build?) and transfer the created files to your Windows into correct folders in Symbian SDK. That should be enough for your purposes if you don't have to debug or modify them. I did similar thing with some JSON libraries - I only needed the header and lib files .

Comment: Hi Riho, I found that Qt Creator on MAC cannot build to Symbian target. It mean it cannot build App/library for Symbian....

Comment: Then it's time to buy a computer :)  Windows is not so bad